# How do I change from Intel HD Graphics to Radeon in 16.04?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, radeon

```
sudo lshw -c video
```

I get:

```
*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: HD Graphics 520
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
   resources: irq:277 memory:d1000000-d1ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
*-display
   description: Display controller
   product: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 81
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:278 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d003ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0040000-d005ffff
```

```
$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 [8086:1916] (rev 07)
```

```
$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 3
Provider 0: id: 0x66 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 2 name:Intel
Provider 1: id: 0x3f cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 2 name:HAINAN @ pci:0000:01:00.0
Provider 2: id: 0x3f cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 2 name:HAINAN @ pci:0000:01:00.0
```

Is there anything I can do so I can make it to switch to the radeon?
According to [RadeonDriver - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) the Radeon driver is already pre-installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proprietary Radeon drivers are not supported in 16.04.  Forcing an install, or keeping them installed during an upgrade will cause issues, if you can even get them to install.

For now, 16.04 is using opensource AMD Drivers, but, they're not very good and not reliable.  Performance is also a huge issue.

Unfortunately for those of us using the AMD graphics, we need to wait, and use the Intel HD graphics (If you're lucky to have it) until then.

See:

- [RadeonDriver - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver)
- [Why Radeon Users May Want to Avoid Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04)

Comment: is this issue fixed in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS ?

Comment: @Jrct I wouldn't know, I switched to Nvidia graphics because of lack of AMD support.