# AMD Graphics card not getting used in Ubuntu 16.04 Lenovo Thinkpad E460

Tags: drivers, graphics, lenovo, thinkpad, amd-graphics

I am unable to use Amd graphics driver in ubuntu. When I run the command

```
    lspci -nn | grep VGA
```

Output:

```
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 [8086:1916] (rev 07)
```

I am not seeing my graphics card. Is there any way to configure the graphics card on my 6th gen machine?

Possible related issue: [16.04 change from Intel HD Graphics to Radeon](https://askubuntu.com/questions/772337/16-04-change-from-intel-hd-graphics-to-radeon?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

With Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, AMD graphics cards won't work properly with older computers.  If you want to use your graphics card, downgrade to Ubuntu 15.10, or if you want the long term support, use 14.04 LTS.

Comment: Mine is 6th gen machine, I know 7th gen machines are out but 6th gen has skylake architecture which 7th gen machines also shares. I don't think it has something to do with "old machines". Please correct me here if I am wrong.

Comment: Okay all I know is that 16.04 removed a lot of graphical support for older computers so that could be it, or it could be something else.  I wasn't aware that Lenovo has made more recent ThinkPads - I use the z61t, I believe from 2002

Comment: No Problem but thanks for sharing the information.

Comment: No problem :) Happy to help, even if it didn't really help :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the drivers from here. [Download](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/linux#)

When Ubuntu 16.04 was released, it did not have drivers for Radeon cards. However, they were released afterwards.